# Consumiendo un service de la web api en mvc?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

estoy tratando de consumir service de la web api via httpwebrequest y razor para mostrarlo en la vista en mvc. en el controller mvc tengo este codigo en que quiero consumir la api

```
using EntradaElectronicaAlmacenApi.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EntradaElectronicaAlmacen.Controllers
{
    public class InicioController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Inicio
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // get: opciones
        public ActionResult PantallaOpciones()
        {
            HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49851/api/motivo/motivos");
            myReq.ContentType = "application/json";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
            string text;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var motivos = new MotivoService();
            var result = motivos.ObtenerMotivos();
            var rr = Json(new { motivos = text });
            ViewData["motivos"] = rr;
            return View();



        }
    }
}
```

y en la view quiero generar unos botones con los datos que quiero consumir de la api tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Pantalla Opciones</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
@if (ViewData["motivos"] != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var motivo in ViewData["motivos"] as List<EntradaElectronicaAlmacenApi.Infraestructura.Motivos>)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <button id="@motivo.Motivo_Id.ToString()-btn" class="boton3d2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopUpAcceso">@motivo.Descripcion</button>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
</div>
</body>
```

pero me genera el siguiente error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntradaElectronicaAlmacenApi.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No connection string named
>   'EntradaElectronicaAlmacenEntities' could be found in the application
>   config file.

cual podra ser el error que eh investigado y no lo encuentro...

Comment: Te recomiendo usar restsharp para hacer requests en tu aplicación, es mucho más sencillo y completo, o al menos usar System.Net.Http (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), también usar un modelo y no el ViewData para evitar esas conversiones inseguras y por último, el error es de configuración como ya dijo @Einer, el segundo es por un null, revisa que te está respondiendo el servicio, haz debug, saca el request y response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjunto mi solucion al problema que plantie anteriormente por si alguien llega en algun momento a necesitarla.

```
private readonly WebApi _webApi;
        public InicioController()
        {
            _webApi = new WebApi("http://localhost:49851/api/");
        }
```

Estableci una funcion privada en el controller que me permitiera desarializar el objecto ya que me devolvia solo una lista. Luego trabaje con httpClient de esta forma para llenar una lista y deserializar un objeto para poder usar los datos.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PantallaOpciones()
        {
            var response = await _webApi.Get("motivo/motivos");

            if(response.TipoRepuesta != "Error")
            {
                ViewData["Motivos"] = response.Contenido.DeserializeToListEntity<Motivo>();
            }
            return View();           
        }
```

y en mi vista del controller cambie solo un poco la visualizacion de los datos.

```
 @if (ViewData["Motivos"] != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var motivo in (List<EntradaElectronicaAlmacen.Models.Dtos.Motivo>)ViewData["Motivos"])
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <button id="@motivo.Motivo_Id.ToString()-btn" class="boton3d5 clMotivo" data-id="@motivo.Motivo_Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopUpAcceso">
                                    @motivo.Descripcion
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }          
      y con eso pude llamar los botones en base a los datos que tenia en mi base de datos
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu error quiere decir que en no se encuentra la cadena de conexión de nombre `EntradaElectronicaAlmacenEntities` en tu web.config.

Por ejemplo, deberias de tener algo asi en el `web.config`:

```
<configuration>  
    <connectionStrings>  
      <clear />  
      <add name="EntradaElectronicaAlmacenEntities"   
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   
       connectionString="aqui_cadena_conexion_valida_a_tu_server_de_base_de_datos" />  
    </connectionStrings>  
  </configuration>
```

Nota: favor no confundir con el `web.config` que esta en el folder /Views.

Comment: esta coneccion la tengo en el proyecto web api tambien debo tenerla en el proyecto mvc desde donde quiero consumir la api, intente establecer esa coneccion y me genera la siguiente exception:

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_jnxafczk.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Si, eso es un valor nulo probablemente no relacionado a tu pregunta. Donde te lanza el error?

Comment: foreach (var motivo in ViewData["motivos"] as List<EntradaElectronicaAlmacenApi.Infraestructura.Motivos>)

Comment: En esa linea me genera el error como referencia a objeto no establecida

Comment: Esa es otra pregunta ya tu error del web.config se resolvió. Si quieres acepta la respuesta y has otra pregunta detallando ese error